# Why is my scrolltop function scrolling to different parts of the page depending on my position, only on mobile?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a function that scrolls to an element when a button is clicked. The problem is this does not work correctly on mobile. Only when at the top of the page and clicking the button, it scrolls to the correct position. But if I scroll to any other position, the function somehow gets affected and the page scrolls to a different position than the element. Why? On desktop it works fine.

My jquery:

```
$('.stelsamenknop').click(function(e){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#aantalenformaat").offset().top - 20
    }, 1000);
});
```

How can I make sure it always scrolls to the element `aantalenformaat` no matter what position the user is scrolled to on the page?

The button html:

```
<a class="stelsamenknop" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="pr-1 icon-cart"></i> Stel je product samen</a>
```

And the element further down the page:

```
<form id="aantalenformaat" method="post">
```

Comment: In what way doesn't it work on mobile?

Comment: @tree The function never scrolls to exactly that element. If I scroll a bit down the page and click the button, it scrolls to a different position than when I click the button when at the top of the page for example.

Answer (score 0):

Targeting an element specifically or even a fixed offset isn't going to work for all screen sizes. Unless you're accepting of the "close enough" approach. Take into account the changes in element height adapting to the screen size plus any changes to the margins/padding that are present.